# androidPlot black border

Tags: java, android, androidplot

When i execute the code bellow and add in  `mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getBorderPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);`

the app crashes when i launch it on my device.

what i'm trying to accomplish is getting rid of the black border around the entire graph. it is about 2cm thick on located on the top, left and bottom sides of the chart. Is there any way i can get rid of this black border?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 // Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
    Number[] days =   { 1  , 2   , 3   , 4   , 5   , 6   , 7 };
    Number[] values = { 380, 1433, 1965, 3200, 3651, 3215, 3217 };

    // initialize our XYPlot reference:
    mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setBorderStyle(XYPlot.BorderStyle.NONE, null, null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);



    // Domain
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelPaint(null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainOriginLinePaint(null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, days.length);     
    mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));


    //Range
    mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().setRangeOriginLinePaint(null);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, values.length);
    mySimpleXYPlot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));


    //Remove legend
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getLegendWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getDomainLabelWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getRangeLabelWidget());
    mySimpleXYPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(mySimpleXYPlot.getTitleWidget());

    // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
            Arrays.asList(days),          
            Arrays.asList(values), 
            "Series1");                             // Set the display title of the series

    // Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer:
    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
            Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),                   // line color
            Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),                   // point color
            Color.CYAN);                            // fill color 

 // setup our line fill paint to be a slightly transparent gradient:
    Paint lineFill = new Paint();
    lineFill.setAlpha(200);
    lineFill.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 250, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));

    series1Format.setFillPaint(lineFill);

    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    // by default, AndroidPlot displays developer guides to aid in laying out your plot.
    // To get rid of them call disableAllMarkup():
    mySimpleXYPlot.disableAllMarkup();
}

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to get rid of all of the color behind your graph, you will need the following three methods. Each of which gets rid of different parts.

```
//This gets rid of the gray grid
mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

//This gets rid of the black border (up to the graph) there is no black border around the labels
mysimpleXYPlot.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

//This gets rid of the black behind the graph
mySimpleXYPlot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

//With a new release of AndroidPlot you have to also set the border paint
plot.getBorderPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: FWIW I had to call `mXYPlot.setPlotMargin{Left, Right, Top, Bottom}(0);`  to get all the borders hidden.

Comment: @Diederik, I think I love you.

Answer (score 3):

Border line can be hidden by this method:

```
plot.setBorderPaint(null);
plot.setPlotMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to fix the graph with this information but I had to pull together the information from several of these posts. There appears to be 4 different background areas:
* grid (and axis labels)
* area around the graph
* border around the graph.
* margin around the border

1. The background color for the grid and range/domain labels are set using
   `plot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(background_color);`
2. The area round the grid can get set by:
   `plot.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(background_color);`
3. This still leaves a border that is drawn around the graph. You can either get rid of the border:
   `plot.setBorderPaint(null);`

or set the background color

`plot.getBorderPaint().setColor(background_color);`

4. This leaves the margin around the entire plot. This can be removed using 
   `plot.setPlotMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);`

There should be a way to change the color for the margin instead of just removing it but didn't bother to figure that out.