# Android plot removing the black border or change the color of border to white

Tags: android, androidplot

I tried lot of methods to remove the black border in the android plot .. But none of them is working.
When I tried this method

```
  dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getBorderPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

it is crashing..

this the code used for plotting

```
   dynamicPlot = (MultitouchPlot) findViewById(R.id.dynamicPlot);
    dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(color.white);
    createNewGraph(dynamicPlot, 150);

    dynamicPlot.setDomainLabel("Sensor data logging");
    dynamicPlot.setDomainBoundaries(0, 110, BoundaryMode.FIXED);

    historyData = new SimpleXYSeries(" Reading");
    historyData.useImplicitXVals();
    dynamicPlot.addSeries(historyData,
            new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.BLUE,
                    Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE , null));
    dynamicPlot.setDomainStepValue(5);
    //dynamicPlot.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    //dynamicPlot.setGridPadding(0,0 ,0,0);
    dynamicPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
            dynamicPlot.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            //dynamicPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(dynamicPlot.removeXMarkers());
    dynamicPlot.getDomainLabelWidget().pack();
    dynamicPlot.setRangeLabel("Units");
    dynamicPlot.getRangeLabelWidget().pack();
    dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget()
            .setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
    dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(
            new DecimalFormat("0"));



    dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
       dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLabelPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    dynamicPlot.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);

        //dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    //dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    //dynamicPlot.getGraphWidget().getBorderPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Help me to remove this black border[image: This is the screen shot of the graph application]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and this question solved it :

> [androidPlot black border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220821/androidplot-black-border)

All you have to do is :

```
dynamicPlot.setPlotMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and there will be no more black border.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you have turned to null the GridBackgroundPaint before call the method

```
plot.getGraphWidget().setGridBackgroundPaint(null);
```

or something like that in the upper lines.